# Declaring a numpy boolean mask in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

How should I declare the type of a boolean mask in Cython? Do I actually need to declare it? Here is the example:

```
cpdef my_func(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_a,
            np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_b,
            np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_c):

    mask = ((array_a > 1) & (array_b == 2) & (array_c == 3)
    array_a[mask] = 0.
    array_b[mask] = array_c[mask]
    return array_a, array_b, array_c
```

Comment: Just to be complete, your question probably needs more info: the actual error message and the way you constructed `array_a`&Co

Comment: My guess: it should be `np.bool` and not `np.uint8_t`, i.e. `cdef np.ndarray[np.bool, ndim = 2] mask...`

Comment: @ead it gives Invalid type error when using `cdef np.ndarray[np.bool, ndim = 2] `

Comment: Can I declare the type wherever in the code or it has to be at the first lines after def?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "cast" `np.uint8_t` to `bool` via `np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim = 2, cast=True] mask = ...`,  i.e.

```
cimport numpy as np
cpdef my_func(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_a,
            np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_b,
            np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] array_c):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim = 2, cast=True] mask = (array_a > 1) & (arr
ay_b == 2) & (array_c == 3)
    array_a[mask] = 0.
    array_b[mask] = array_c[mask]
    return array_a, array_b, array_c
```

otherwise (without `cast=True`) the code compiles but throws during the runtime because of the type mismatch.

However, you don't need to define the type of `mask` at all and can use it as a python-object: there will be some performance penalty or, more precise, a missed opportunity to speed things a little bit up by early type binding, but in your case it probably doesn't matter anyway.

---

One more thing: I don't know how you real code looks like, but I hope you are aware, that cython won't speedup your example at all - there is nothing to gain compared to numpy.

---

We can easily verify, that a bool-np.array uses 8bit per a value (at least on my system). This is not obvious at all, for example it could use only a bit per value (a lot like a `bitset`):

```
import sys
import numpy as np
a=np.random.random((10000,))
sys.getsizeof(a)
>>> 80096
sys.getsizeof(a<.5)
>>> 10096
```

It is pretty obvious the double array needs 8 bytes per element + 86 bytes overhead, the mask needs only one byte per element.

We can also see, that `False` is represented by `0`  and `True` by `1`:

```
print (a<.5).view(np.uint8)
[1 0 1 ..., 0 0 1]
```

Using  `cast=True` make it possible to access the raw bytes in the underlying array, a kind of reinterpret_cast of the array-memory.

[Here](http://cython-docs2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) is some, albeit old, information.

Comment: Why Cython wont speed up this code? Is it because using numpy in it's optimised way?

Comment: @BehzadJamali There is no "work" in this function - it only calls the numpy-functionality - there is nothing to speed up. Numpy is mostly precompiled C-code, so it is not very probably you will speed it up by rewriting the functionality in cython.